# Браузер работает, а ping нет

Tags: firewall, ping

На XP SP3 работает opera (в нашем случае открывает сайт ya.ru)
При этом из консоли (cmd) нет пинга на ya.ru (не резолвится)

Что это может быть?

Comment: на ya.ru заблокированы пинги.

Comment: это не так, можете сами проверить. Тут именно не резолвится имя. Почему в опере резолвится, а в консоли нет?

Comment: @vinnitu 

Обмен пакетами с ya.ru [77.88.21.3] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 77.88.21.3: число байт=32 время=4мс TTL=58


У вас что-то не так.

Comment: я об этом же :) вопрос - _что_ не так?

Comment: Когда у меня была такая проблема - в сети был "умный" свитч, который выполнял функции DHCP сервера, он гробил все пинги.

Кроме того, пока его не нашли, были проблемы с DHCP от сервера.

Comment: не работает не только ping, не работает и wget с "unknown host"

Comment: По IP адресу попробуйте. Если работает, то какая-то проблема с DNS. 

Если не работает, то в каком-то из роутеров на пути к ya.ru запрещен ICMP.

Comment: Если Вы работаете через прокси, то сам DNS для Вас вполне может быть абстрактной величиной (Ваш хост может и не знать его адреса). Все адреса разрешаются для прокси-сервера, а Вы получаете результат запроса.

Answer (score 1):

В Opera есть свой локальный DNS Cache, куда собственно и закешировался адрес ya.ru.
Это функция называется насколько помню - Work Offline, на русском языке вроде "Автономная работа" в настройках, вот она и закешировала этот адрес.

из cmd, ping берет сначала в hosts настройки записей А, а потом уже с DNS сервера, который судя по всему или не работает, или не настроен.

Проверить, есть ли он в настройках - всегда можно через ipconfig /all
Проверить работу самого DNS сервера можно командой nslookup.

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в том что все было закрыто, а браузер ходил через прокси

Comment: Как пел хор в известном мультфильме "Предчувствия его не обманули"

Только если Вы работает в сети с приватными адресами, то "закрыто" -- слово неправильное. Просто Вас для интернета не существует, а существует Ваш "представитель" (proxy), который выполняет для Вас необходимую работу.

Comment: возможно все открылось бы значительно раньше, если бы машина была моя ))